# Chrome Extension to unblock a blocked url using webrequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blocking, chrome-webrequest

I am trying to unblock a blocked URL using chrome.webrequest api,I went through the api documentation and implemented.It is blocking the url ,but after it ,when i run the unblock part of the code ,it is not unblocking the url.Below,is the code for the unblocking part.Is there a way ?
  `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return { } },
    {urls: ["url to be unblocked "]},
    ["requestBody"]);`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by unblocking. There's no such thing in webRequest API. Describe in detail what your extension does and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Actually , I have two functions - one to block the url and the other to unblock the url ,unblock means to unblock the url blocked by the block function.I am asking ,is there any way we can do it in webrequest - to block the url ,i used the above mechanism `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
        {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
        ["blocking"]);`

Comment: Simply remove the listener and add it without that site in the list of URLs.

Comment: Thanks,It worked and I didnt though of removeListener during developing !